# Remove solution from Team Foundation service

Tags: azure-devops

I add solution in team fundation service in the worng place.
Can I remove the soution from the source control and add it to the right place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `Move...` the solution in Visual Studio Source Control Explorer (if you are using TFVC). Just open Visual Studio, leaving you solution closed, use Source Control Explorer to "Move" the folder to the new path, then check in the Pending Changes.

If you are using Git, then there are ways to do that too, but I'd probably need a little more information about your repositories to answer.